# Programmatically Add Form and Controls

Tags: vb.net, forms

I have the following code;
I added a second form and controls Programmatically to it but the timer is not working properly in the second form;
Of course it is working properly in the main form;
I need help on doing the exact same thing in the second form as what I've done in the main form;
Thanks in advance for help;

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frmNew As New Form
        frmNew.Visible = True
        Dim Label2 As New Label()
        frmNew.Controls.Add(Label2)
        Label2.Name = "Label1"
        oTimer = New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        oTimer.Interval = 1000
        oTimer.Enabled = True
        oTimer.Start()
        frmNew.Text = Date.Now
        Label2.Text = Date.Now
    End Sub
    Private WithEvents oTimer As System.Windows.Forms.Timer
    Private Sub timerTicks() Handles oTimer.Tick
        Me.Text = Date.Now
        label1.text = Date.Now
        'frmNew.Text = Date.Now
        'frmNew.Label2.Text = Date.Now
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: you dont have a timer tick event in frmNew.  `timerticks` is private to Form1, so frmNew (and the controls on it) can use it.

Comment: You also are not adding your timer to Form2

Comment: Why don't you want to design this form and show it? A blank new form has all the defaults and will not look as good as a form you get to design.

Comment: Plutonix; Can you tell me how to: "add a timer tick event in frmNew. timerticks is private to Form1, so frmNew (and the controls on it) can use it.", please?  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to somehow pass a reference to both the Form and the Label into the Tick() event of the Timer.  Here's one way to do it:

```
Public Class Form1

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim frmNew As New Form
        Dim Label2 As New Label()
        frmNew.Controls.Add(Label2)
        Dim tmr As New System.Windows.Forms.Timer
        AddHandler tmr.Tick, AddressOf tmr_Tick
        tmr.Tag = New Tuple(Of Control, Control)(frmNew, Label2)
        tmr.Interval = 1000
        tmr.Start()
        frmNew.Text = Date.Now
        Label2.Text = Date.Now
        frmNew.Show()
    End Sub

    Private Sub tmr_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        Dim T As Tuple(Of Control, Control) = DirectCast(DirectCast(sender, System.Windows.Forms.Timer).Tag, Tuple(Of Control, Control))
        Dim frm As Form = DirectCast(T.Item1, Form)
        Dim lbl As Label = DirectCast(T.Item2, Label)
        Dim curTime As String = DateTime.Now.ToString("h:mm:ss tt")
        frm.Text = curTime
        lbl.Text = curTime
    End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: Hi Idle_MindThanks a lot for the help;  One last question, if I run the code; I got the frm.Text showing the seconds; but the lbl.Text showing only the month and day; is there a way to show the hours, minutes and seconds for the lbl?

Comment: Wonderful; Thanks Idle_Mind; I tired to "Vote-Up"; But not allowed because I need to be level 15 or more; sorry for that.  I really appreciate your help.